# I am intended to insert unordered list in my nav tab through JS using innerHTML property however it is not working

Tags: html-lists

```
let div_nav = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < nav_tabs.length; i++) {
    div_nav += "<li>"+nav_tabs[i]+"</li>"; 
}
div_nav += "</ul>";
console.log(div_nav);

document.getElementsByClassName("nav").innerHTML = div_nav;
```

I am intended to insert unordered list in my nav tab through JS using innerHTML property however it is not working.

Comment: You're trying to set the innerHTML of an array.  That's not gonna work.  Loop through the elements in your array to change the innerHTML of each one.

Comment: nav_tabs is an array where as div_nav is a variable string type, i m intended to add this string as inner HTML and hopping it will work as html tabs, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Since classes are not unique therefore getElementsByClassName returns an array. Therefore i tried below and it worked.

document.getElementsByClassName("nav").innerHTML = div_nav;